# Interdependent Properties with INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF-UI with two datepickers. The first datepicker sets the current Date, the second datepicker sets a reference Date. Based on these two dates selected in the datepickers data is loaded into a grid and their change over time is displayed.

The problem i have now is that selecting the current Date should of course affect the reference Date in such a way, that when the current Date is behind the reference Date, the reference Date should be automatically set to be one day behind the selected Date. E.g.:

```
CurrentDate   = new Datetime(2016,09,12); // Selected to be the 12th
if(ReferenceDate > CurrentDate)
    ReferenceDate = CurrentDate.AddDays(-1)
```

The data is now reloaded in the datagrid whenever the date changes. In this case this means i have to reload the data when a current Date is selected, but i also have to reload the data when the reference Date is selected. Applying the method above leads to calling the loadData method twice tough.

```
propertyChanged(parameters...) {
    if(CurrentDate)
        loadData(); // Selecting the CurrentDate will load Data
    if(ReferenceDate)
        loadData(); // Automatically changing the RefDate will load the data a second time
}
```

(The code snippets are just to illustrate the problem, they are not actual code)

I would be thankful for any ideas on how to implement a mechanism that allows to only raise a notification once for the whole date selection operation.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to choose DP over INPC. DP allows [Coercion, and Validation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745795%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). 
But still if you want to use INPC, you can change RefDate in the setter of CurDate, and raise `OnPropertyChanged("ReferenceDate")` from `CurrentDate` setter itself.

Comment: I thought DependecyProperties should only be used when i want to access a self-defined property through the ui.

Comment: @narain Downside with DP is it must be define in a DO.